# How to print piecewise functions in GNU Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, gnu

How does one print out a piecewise function in GNU Octave in a human readable way?

Somehow produce output similar to this in either the console or a file: x^(4) + x^(3) + x^(2) + x + 1 for each polynomial in the piecewise function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *fprintf* in MATLAB to write the polynomial you want into a file. Check the below code:

```
str = 'x^(4) + x^(3) + x^(2) + x + 1' ;
fid = fopen('check.txt','w') ;
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',str) ;
fclose(fid) ;
```